# iOS,Why does iCloud sync Object on 2nd device but does not sync Object's property

Tags: ios, synchronization, relationship, icloud, nsmanagedobjectcontext

> iOS iCloud does sync Object on 2nd device but does not sync Object's property

- NonSyncing property: categories
- App: Universal iOS, CoreData Library Style, with FRCs handling tableViews, no GarbageCollection
- Devices: iPhone 4, iPad 1 both on 5.1.1 both are running same iOS app.
- XCode 4.3.2
- DataModel:

## ** Entity       Relationship    Destination     Inverse **

```
   Recipe       categories      Category        recipes

   Category     recipes         Recipe          categories
```

- Relevant Objects: Recipe and Category, first has optional to-many property categories, 
  second has has paired optional to-many property recipes.
  Other properties of Recipe include ingredients , an NSString*
- Procedure: on iPad app creates a new Recipe in the MOC and to it I add an existing category to the Recipe obj, 
  and then some ingredients text. I then save: to the MOC, -- the only save: call. The new Recipe is synced on the iPhone with ingredients text, 
  but it lacks the category that was added and saved on the iPad. This search category 'works' on the iPad, where it was added, but not on 
  the iPhone, that is, the category is not added to the categories property of the new Recipe of the 2nd device.
  iCloud puts two *.cdt files on the iPhone.

Below are Class interface and implementation files for Recipe and Category and the contents plist from the two Log files that appear on the iPhone

- Questions:
  I hope this enough info for you to advise me where to look for a fix? I am uncertain what info to supply here.
  Shouldn't iCloud handle this property syncing on its own?

Thank you for reading this! Mark

```
    // Recipe.h

    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

    @class Category;
    @class Photo;

    @interface Recipe :  NSManagedObject  
    {

    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * recipeID;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * ctime;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ingredients;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * comments;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nameShort;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * directions;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * ptime;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* photos;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* categories;

    - (NSComparisonResult)compareRecipeNames:(Recipe *)recipe;

    @end


    @interface Recipe (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
    - (void)addPhotosObject:(Photo *)value;
    - (void)removePhotosObject:(Photo *)value;
    - (void)addPhotos:(NSSet *)value;
    - (void)removePhotos:(NSSet *)value;

    - (void)addCategoriesObject:(Category *)value;
    - (void)removeCategoriesObject:(Category *)value;
    - (void)addCategories:(NSSet *)value;
    - (void)removeCategories:(NSSet *)value;

    @end

    // 
    //  Recipe.m


    #import "Recipe.h"

    #import "Category.h"
    #import "Photo.h"

    @implementation Recipe

    @dynamic name;
    @dynamic recipeID;
    @dynamic ctime;
    @dynamic ingredients;
    @dynamic comments;
    @dynamic nameShort;
    @dynamic directions;
    @dynamic ptime;
    @dynamic junk;
    @dynamic photos;
    @dynamic categories;


    - (id)init{

        self = [super init];

        return self;
    }


    - (void)addCategories:(NSSet *)value{

        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"categories"
                        withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
                            usingObjects:value];

        [[self primitiveCategories] unionSet:value];

        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"categories"
                      withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
                          usingObjects:value];

    }


    - (void)addCategoriesObject:(Category *)value 
    {    
        NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];

        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"categories" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"categories"] addObject:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"categories" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];

        [changedObjects release];
    }

    - (void)removeCategoriesObject:(Category *)value 
    {
        NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];

        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"categories" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"categories"] removeObject:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"categories" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];

        [changedObjects release];
    }

    - (void)addPhotosObject:(Photo *)value 
    {    
        NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];

        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"photos" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"photos"] addObject:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"photos" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];

        [changedObjects release];
    }

    - (void)removePhotosObject:(Photo *)value 
    {
        NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];

        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"photos" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"photos"] removeObject:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"photos" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];

        [changedObjects release];
    }


    - (NSComparisonResult)compareRecipeNames:(Recipe *)recipe  {
        // Compare nodes to each other by comparing the data part.
        return [self.name compare:[recipe name] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    }


    @end

    -- Category.h

    //Category.h

    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

    @class Recipe;

    @interface Category :  NSManagedObject  
    {
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nameShort;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* recipes;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* sortIndex;

    - (NSComparisonResult) compareCategoryNames:(Category *)category ;
    - (NSComparisonResult) compareCategorySortIndeces:(Category *)category;

    @end


    @interface Category (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
    - (void)addRecipesObject:(Recipe *)value;
    - (void)removeRecipesObject:(Recipe *)value;
    - (void)addRecipes:(NSSet *)value;
    - (void)removeRecipes:(NSSet *)value;

    @end


    // 
    //  Category.m
    //

    #import "Category.h"
    #import "Recipe.h"

    @implementation Category 

    @dynamic nameShort;
    @dynamic name;
    @dynamic recipes;
    @dynamic sortIndex;


    - (void)addRecipesObject:(Recipe *)value 
    {    
        NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];

        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"recipes" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"recipes"] addObject:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"recipes" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];

        [changedObjects release];
    }

    - (void)removeRecipesObject:(Recipe *)value 
    {
        NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];

        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"recipes" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"recipes"] removeObject:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"recipes" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];

        [changedObjects release];
    }


    - (NSComparisonResult) compareCategoryNames:(Category *)category
    {
        return [[self name] localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: [category name]];
    }

    - (NSComparisonResult) compareCategorySortIndeces:(Category *)category
    {

         if ([self sortIndex] > [category    sortIndex]) {
              return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
         }

         if ([self sortIndex] < [category sortIndex]) {
              return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
         }
         return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }


    @end
```

-- first plist from cdt file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>compressedGlobalIDs</key>
        <array>
            <string>0:0:0</string>
            <string>1:1:0</string>
            <string>0:2:0</string>
            <string>0:3:0</string>
            <string>0:4:0</string>
            <string>0:5:0</string>
            <string>0:6:0</string>
            <string>0:7:0</string>
            <string>0:8:0</string>
            <string>0:9:0</string>
            <string>0:10:0</string>
            <string>0:11:0</string>
            <string>0:12:0</string>
            <string>0:13:0</string>
        </array>
        <key>deleted</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>entityNames</key>
        <array>
            <string>Recipe</string>
            <string>Category</string>
        </array>
        <key>inserted</key>
        <dict>
            <key>0</key>
            <dict>
                <key>categories</key>
                <array>
                    <string>1</string>
                </array>
                <key>ctime</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>Aaa Rx D</string>
                <key>photos</key>
                <array/>
                <key>ptime</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>recipeID</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>kvStr</key>
        <string>mobile.F0F5BE6D-59A3-5D63-A0B2-4767EFECC603:1</string>
        <key>modelVersionHash</key>
        <string>9FRYa_LmmBTIAw8875pOlLyYmr5vrP1Hwi~lgvsHL1k=</string>
        <key>peerIDs</key>
        <array>
            <string>mobile.F0F5BE6D-59A3-5D63-A0B2-4767EFECC603</string>
        </array>
        <key>peerStates</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>primaryKeys</key>
        <array>
            <string>p89</string>
            <string>p6</string>
            <string>p43</string>
            <string>p4</string>
            <string>p41</string>
            <string>p5</string>
            <string>p52</string>
            <string>p58</string>
            <string>p68</string>
            <string>p13</string>
            <string>p79</string>
            <string>p28</string>
            <string>p17</string>
            <string>p25</string>
        </array>
        <key>transactionDate</key>
        <real>1343676810.7298651</real>
        <key>transactionNumber</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>updated</key>
        <dict>
            <key>1</key>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>Desserts</string>
                <key>recipes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>2</string>
                    <string>3</string>
                    <string>4</string>
                    <string>5</string>
                    <string>6</string>
                    <string>7</string>
                    <string>8</string>
                    <string>9</string>
                    <string>0</string>
                    <string>10</string>
                    <string>11</string>
                    <string>12</string>
                    <string>13</string>
                </array>
                <key>sortIndex</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

-second plist

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>compressedGlobalIDs</key>
        <array>
            <string>0:0:0</string>
            <string>1:1:0</string>
            <string>0:2:0</string>
            <string>0:3:0</string>
            <string>0:4:0</string>
            <string>0:5:0</string>
            <string>0:6:0</string>
            <string>0:7:0</string>
            <string>0:8:0</string>
            <string>0:9:0</string>
            <string>0:10:0</string>
            <string>0:11:0</string>
            <string>0:12:0</string>
            <string>0:13:0</string>
        </array>
        <key>deleted</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>entityNames</key>
        <array>
            <string>Recipe</string>
            <string>Category</string>
        </array>
        <key>inserted</key>
        <dict>
            <key>0</key>
            <dict>
                <key>categories</key>
                <array>
                    <string>1</string>
                </array>
                <key>ctime</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>Aaa Rx D</string>
                <key>photos</key>
                <array/>
                <key>ptime</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>recipeID</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>kvStr</key>
        <string>mobile.F0F5BE6D-59A3-5D63-A0B2-4767EFECC603:1</string>
        <key>modelVersionHash</key>
        <string>9FRYa_LmmBTIAw8875pOlLyYmr5vrP1Hwi~lgvsHL1k=</string>
        <key>peerIDs</key>
        <array>
            <string>mobile.F0F5BE6D-59A3-5D63-A0B2-4767EFECC603</string>
        </array>
        <key>peerStates</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>primaryKeys</key>
        <array>
            <string>p89</string>
            <string>p6</string>
            <string>p43</string>
            <string>p4</string>
            <string>p41</string>
            <string>p5</string>
            <string>p52</string>
            <string>p58</string>
            <string>p68</string>
            <string>p13</string>
            <string>p79</string>
            <string>p28</string>
            <string>p17</string>
            <string>p25</string>
        </array>
        <key>transactionDate</key>
        <real>1343676810.7298651</real>
        <key>transactionNumber</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>updated</key>
        <dict>
            <key>1</key>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>Desserts</string>
                <key>recipes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>2</string>
                    <string>3</string>
                    <string>4</string>
                    <string>5</string>
                    <string>6</string>
                    <string>7</string>
                    <string>8</string>
                    <string>9</string>
                    <string>0</string>
                    <string>10</string>
                    <string>11</string>
                    <string>12</string>
                    <string>13</string>
                </array>
                <key>sortIndex</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

## - message following the only MOC save:

2012-07-31 12:38:44.632 iHungryMePlus[688:1b03] +PFUbiquityBaseline metadataFromCurrentBaselineForStoreWithName:modelVersionHash:andUbiquityRootLocation:withError:: CoreData: Ubiquity:  Didn't get baseline metadata back from metadata url: file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3PAT8SS34X~com~DrummingGrouse~iHMP/.baseline/current.nosync/com.DrummingGrouse.iHMP.mainstore/9FRYa_LmmBTIAw8875pOlLyYmr5vrP1Hwi~lgvsHL1k=/baseline.meta

Error: (null)

2012-07-31 12:38:44.818 iHungryMePlus[688:1b03] +PFUbiquityBaseline metadataFromCurrentBaselineForStoreWithName:modelVersionHash:andUbiquityRootLocation:withError:: CoreData: Ubiquity:  Didn't get baseline metadata back from metadata url: file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3PAT8SS34X~com~DrummingGrouse~iHMP/.baseline/current.nosync/com.DrummingGrouse.iHMP.mainstore/9FRYa_LmmBTIAw8875pOlLyYmr5vrP1Hwi~lgvsHL1k=/baseline.meta

Error: (null)

2012-07-31 12:38:44.824 iHungryMePlus[688:1b03] -PFUbiquityBaselineRecoveryOperation main: CoreData: Ubiquity:   localPeerID: mobile.F0F5BE6D-59A3-5D63-A0B2-4767EFECC603, storeName: com.DrummingGrouse.iHMP.mainstore, modelVersionHash: 9FRYa_LmmBTIAw8875pOlLyYmr5vrP1Hwi~lgvsHL1k=

```
ubiquityRootLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x162e10>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3PAT8SS34X~com~DrummingGrouse~iHMP
```

Got nil for current baseline metadata, (null)

Comment: The answer to your question as to if this should work, the answer is 'probably' (there are some particulars but based on my quick read, what you're trying to do should work). Question: do any of your models have validations / rules on them that could possibly prevent the changes from saving properly?

Comment: Anyone interested in iCloud should be aware of http://mentalfaculty.tumblr.com/post/23231176783/under-the-sheets-with-icloud-and-core-data-how-it. Thanks Hunter, I appreciated your input.

Comment: You don't explain how you create the Category object on the iPad and whether this category object is being synced to the iPhone.  Check whether this category object is being synced correctly.